# Understanding take an interest in collocation

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, collocations

I'm trying to understand the exact meaning and usage of `take an interest in`. There are several examples of the collocation in various dictionaries:

[#1](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take_1#take_1__37) [#2](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+an+interest)

What is the most common circumstances in which we use the idiom in place of, say, just ***to be interested in***. Examples from the dicitonaries:

> Do you take an interest in your children? You should take an interest in 
>   everything your child does.

Why don't we just say

> Are you interested in your children. You should be interested in
>   everything your child does.

What is the differences?

Or this one:

> ‘What do you mean?’ asked Pat, now taking an interest in the
>   proceedings.

As far as I got, the meaning of `take an interest` here is that your interest is getting increased. But why don't we say

> now I'm becoming more interested in the proceedings

instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*take an interest* implies a personal involvement, beyond just wanting to study something (being interested).

This would be the case in:

> You should **take an interest** in everything your child does.

In the case of:

> You **should be interested** in everything your child does.

it is like you are watching your children/studying their actions, and that appeals to you somehow. However this does not require any action on your part.

The same for:

> 'What do you mean?' asked Pat, now **taking an interest** in the proceedings.

shows his involvement, while:

> Now I'm **becoming more interested** in the proceedings.

is like you are reading an article in the newspaper or hearing someone talk about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not happy with the example given at Macmillan, "He's never taken much interest in his kids."  I would say that should be "He's never *shown* much interest in his kids."

*To take an interest in (something)* means

1) to take it up as an avocation or hobby or
2) to devote attention to it as a matter or topic of importance or relevance

*To show interest in (someone)* means
1) to act in a way that indicates concern for their concerns
2) to act in a way that indicates a willingness or desire to make their acquaintance, especially in an amorous sense